# Mongodb aggregation with $addFileds and condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Given that:

db :

```
{
   id:"112",
   val1: {val:""},
   val2: {val:"123"},
}
```

I would like to run a script that updates a new field according to the aggregation result. The result is true if one of the values (val1, val2) is empty

The below is what I did with aggregation and then I would go over with for and update all rows:

```
db.valTest.aggregate(
    [{
            "$addFields": {
                "val.selected": {
                    '$or': [{
                        'val1.val': ''
                    }, {
                        'val2.val': ''
                    }]

                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "id": {
                    "$first": "$id"
                },
                "value": {
                    "$first": "val1.val"
                },
                "result": {
                    "$push": {
                        "val": "val1.val",
                        "selected": "val.selected"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ]
)
```

But, I do not get the correct result. I would like to get result like:

```
{
   id:"112",
   val1: {val:""},
   val2: {val:"123"},
   result: true
},
{
   id:"114",
   val1: {val:"4545"},
   val2: {val:"123"},
   result: false
}
```

Presently, I am getting the following error:

```
"message" : "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) aggregation operator for the matching criteria

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "result": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$or": [{ "$eq": ["$val1.val", ""] }, { "$eq": ["$val2.val", ""] }] },
        true,
        false
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```